# CKeditor remove extra whitespace

Tags: php, ckeditor

I'm using CKeditor for a text editor and it won't remove extra whitespace.

I've tried

```
$foo = strip_tags($foo);
$foo = preg_replace('/\s+/',' ',$foo);
```

I don't know of any other way to remove whitespace from here. Any ideas?

Thanks

Comment: Thanks, I know this is old, but you just saved me from pulling away what remains of my hair. CKEditor is so hard to work with...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Solved If anybody is curious, I solved this by cleaning them before they went into the database.

```
  $cpbody = trim($_POST['cbody']);

  $cpbody = preg_replace("/\<p\>\&nbsp\;\<\/p\>/", "", $cpbody);
  $cpbody = preg_replace("/\&nbsp\;+/", " ", $cpbody);
  $cpbody = preg_replace("/\s+/", " ", $cpbody);

  $cpbody = htmlentities($cpbody);
```

Answer (score 4):

try these:

```
$foo = preg_replace('/\s{2,}/', ' ', $foo);
```

or

```
$foo = preg_replace('/( )+/', ' ', $foo);
```

or this one removes line breaks too

```
$foo = trim(preg_replace('/[\s\t\n\r\s]+/', ' ', $foo))
```

### Update

Try this one:

```
$foo = trim(preg_replace('/(&nbsp;)+|\s\K\s+/','',$foo));
```

Comment: Thanks Ganesh, I tried all of these codes but it didn't work. I really don't see how it doesn't work. The source code is literally <p> </p> and when I remove those p's there's the space left over. I've also tried preg_replace('/\<p\>\s\<\/p\>/', ' ', $foo); to no avail.

Comment: @Newbie try this one, 
`$foo = trim(preg_replace('/(&nbsp;)+|\s\K\s+/','',$foo));`

Comment: Thanks, but this one also didn't remove the white space. I don't think that it is registered as "&nbsp;". In the mysql database it looks like a normal space.

Comment: @Newbie change the text to utf-8 and try the about preg_replace code!