# WTForms Regexp validator: How to match white space within html tags using regex

Tags: python, regex, flask, flask-wtforms

I have a form with a textarea field and wonder if I could use WTForms Regexp validator to prevent the form submitting when the textarea contains only blank spaces.
Is there a way?

This is my form:

```
class AddReviewForm(FlaskForm):
    review = TextAreaField("Review", validators=[DataRequired())
    submit = SubmitField("Post Review")
```

I was hoping `Regexp` would allow me to prevent only spaces.
My textarea fields include `CKEditor`, which adds `<p>` (or other tags) to the input in order to display it as WYSIWYG.

So in the database the whitespaces look like this:

```
"<p>&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;</p>"
```

And that shouldn't validate.

Comment: do you want the submitted form to be denied by the backend or block submitting all together from the frontend?

Comment: Is it an optional field?

Comment: I’m afraid I’m late for the frontent? I’m dealing with them with my routes in python only. . I’m open to all expertise here, of which I lack. 
@ngShravil.py: it’s the only field besides the submit and it’s data required.

Comment: @GuillermoBrachetta I have added an answer that would hopefully help you. But I highly recommend you to please take a look at this when asking questions [ask] as well as this [MRE] . It make our job as people trying to help easier :D

Comment: Thanks so much and you’re absolutely right. I’ll edit my question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can create a custom validator.

Import `ValidationError`:

```py
from wtforms import ValidationError
```

Custom validator:

```py
def validate_review(self, field):
    text = field.data.replace('<p>','')
                     .replace('</p>','')
                     .replace('&nbsp;','')
                     .replace('&ensp;','')
                     .replace('&emsp;','')
                     .replace('<br>','')
    if not text:
        raise ValidationError('This field should not contain only white spaces')
```

Make sure that, this custom validator is method of `AddReviewForm` class. Also note that, the custom validator's method name should be in the form of `validate_<field_name>`.

Comment: I'm afraid this isn't working for me:

`class AddReviewForm(FlaskForm):
    review = TextAreaField("Review", validators=[DataRequired()])
    submit = SubmitField("Post Review")

    def validate_review(self, review):
        if not review.data.strip():
            raise ValidationError("Your review must have content")`

Comment: No, no error, it's just not preventing the form from validating.
The thing is that CKEditor adds "<p>&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;</p>" so the field is not considered empty, and it's rendered as whitespace.

Comment: Could you print the value of `review.data` just before the `if` condition and let me know what is it printing?

Comment: Yes, it's no break spaces enclosed by p tags:
`<p>&nbsp;&nbsp;</p>`

Comment: If it fails for any of the values, post the value in comments and let me know.

Comment: Wow Shravil, this seems to be working!! Amazing, so many thanks!!

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at this I think this might help you :

[image]

Here is the [link](https://wtforms.readthedocs.io/en/latest/validators/#built-in-validators) to the above image

As you can see from the image above this should satisfy your condition :

*"if the data is a string type, a string containing only whitespace characters is considered false."*

Let me know if that works :D!

Comment: Thanks so much for this. The problem is that I have that text field with CKEditor (a wysiwyg editor for textarea fields), meaning that if I add white space it encloses it in <p> tags, so it’s not anymore considered spaces by the validator.

Comment: It's CKeditor4. Btw, just updated my question. I hope it's clearer now!

Comment: Also , check out the suggestion in this link https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24579078/ckeditor-remove-extra-whitespace  . Let me know if the implmenting the changes in that link helps you solve your issue. @GuillermoBrachetta

Comment: The above linked example is using php, you would just use javscript to apply the same regex.

Comment: Thanks so much, let me try to figure this out, as it looks quite confusing for my level :)

Comment: (I wondered originally if there would be a way to use wtforms Regexp validator in the review field from my code above).

Comment: @GuillermoBrachetta Also try these 2 solution first as they seem to be from the ckeditor forums. https://ckeditor.com/old/forums/CKEditor-3.x/Disable-Whitespace-pretty-printing .  https://ckeditor.com/old/forums/CKEditor/Removing-whitespace . and also this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21846952/ckeditor-validation-for-spaces

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/214940/discussion-between-akib-rhast-and-guillermo-brachetta).